# Strange NSInvalidArgumentException in MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am developing very simple MonoTouch app for a hotel, that contains mainly images and text. No fancy stuff going on.

Everything runs fine in the simulator, but when I load it on an iPhone, some UILabels seem to have disappeared. I have created the view in XCode, no dynamic view creation, just a plain old UILabel that appears fine in the simulator, but is not displayed on the device.

I tried to debug it, by just putting a Debug.Writeline(title==null) in the ViewDidLoad event. In the simulator a "false" is output, but the iPhone crashes with the following:

```
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[UILabel UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x66266d0
```

This is my version info:

MonoDevelop 2.8.6.5
Mono 2.10.8 
Xcode 4.2 (828)
Monotouch: 5.0.4

I really don't know in what direction to look at, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Themos

Comment: Edit your question and show the **complete** stack trace, not just the message, as it could help. Also what's shown in the device logs and the crash report (from the device) would be useful (but they can be huge so it may be better to fill a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and attach the files for the report).

Comment: Thanks poupou. It appears it was related to the font I used. It was Helvetica Neue, so it seems it was an issue related to a font available in the simulator (Mac) but not on the real device. Although I'm sure I've seen this font listed as supported.

Comment: That's weird but I'm glad you got it to work :-) If you have some time please do fill a bug report - it be nice if something nicer could be reported in such cases.